# Any good resource to learn Java programming without any other programming experience?

Tags: java

I've found multiple resources to learn Java programming, but all of them assume prior programming experience with another language.

Does anyone know of a good, preferably entertaining, resource to learn the basics of computer programming using Java?

The reason it must be Java is that the learner will be using it in a course in the near future.

Thank you

Comment: The best thing to do is to just start.  The more you practice the better you get, the more work related experience and you work with others, the better you get.  One definition of a computer expert; someone who has made all the mistakes before. ;)

Comment: People still think learning programming is like learning history from scripts. In fact, it's rather like learning to play an instrument - you don't feel like you want to play, you will never really play.

Answer (score 4):

I found [**this website**](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/) to be very helpful when I first started out with programming.

It goes beyond simply describing the correct syntax for your Java program... rather, it teaches you how programming languages work as a whole (see [chapter 1](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c1/index.html)) and emphasizes good coding style.

Comment: +1 - I've never seen this.  Looks interesting.

Comment: Looks very interesting to me, but the reason I'm asking is that I'm helping my girlfriend, a psychology major, learn programming for her research, and this book goes into quite a lot of detail for someone who will probably never use a lower level language.

Comment: Ahh, then perhaps one of the conventional "Java for Dummies" type books is the way to go. Still, I'd highly recommend this website for those who are interested in learning how to program from a "programmer's" (as opposed to a "Java expert's) point of view.

Comment: Actually, it's not a question of Java expertise, it's a question of knowing the programming logic necessary to use a high level programming language, without the need to understand the underlying architecture.

Attention span is a problem, and I'm fairly certain she won't like learning too much about how memory is managed, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Try the ["Head First"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208) series.  Kathy Sierra has put a lot of thought into making the presentation fun and educational.

Comment: This looks interesting. It does start from no programming experience at all, right? Like, not even conditionals and loops, or boolean algebra?

Comment: I can't say if it'll be at a low enough level.  Perhaps not.

Answer (score 2):

What about this book, [Think Java](http://greenteapress.com/thinkapjava/thinkapjava.pdf)? It started with a introduction of what, that is giving a definition for fresh people to the programming. Read on chapter one, it explain some of the keywords used in programing in a layman term.

The contents are concise and it is only sixteen chapters. Each chapter explaining the example with a few line of codes, not daunting and a few exercises at the end of each chapter. That exercise definitely help in applicable in real life scenario in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jasonw. Think Like a Computer Scientist (Java Version) is a great resource for a few reasons.

1. It doesn't assume prior knowledge. It starts out with "What is a programming language."
2. It teaches computer science concepts instead of just the Java language
3. It's free.

http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkapjava/

Personally, I learned programming on "[Beginning Programming with Java for Dummies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764588745)." It goes slow and doesn't assume anything. I think it even shows you how to get your classpath set up so you can run javac from the command prompt. I used this as a jumping off point (I reordered some chapters and added material) for building my own curriculum when I taught an introduction to programming course.

Comment: +1 Good point on the classpath issue, just search java classpath question in this site, you will be amaze of the result return!